# Perl regex to transform line based on information in line above

Tags: regex, perl, replace

I am trying to outcomment two lines, one following the other, of a text file as part of a perl script. The first line always starts with `file:///` so it's easy to write a regex that finds it but the second line can be any random text so I'm trying to use one regex to match the first line, a linebreak `\n` and then any stuff that comes after that until the next linebreak. But I can't get it to match more than the first line.

```
s/^(file:\/\/\/.*)\n(.*)/\% $1\n\% $2/g;
```

Help much appreciated!

Comment: *and then any stuff that comes after* - how can you define the trailing boundary of the pattern you seek?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Well, the trailing boundary would be the end of the second line, I guess. Sorry, I'm very much a beginner with regexes...

Comment: Ok, but are you reading the data line by line? If yes, you can't match 2 lines with 1  pattern.

Comment: are you sure the line endings are `\n` and not `\r\n` ?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm reading it with `while (<$fh_in>)`, does that always mean line by line?

Comment: Yes. That means you are reading line by line.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  Oh, I get it now.  So I would have to write it before the `while` block then?

Comment: Maybe you can leverage some ideas in  [perl if line matches regex, ignore line and move onto next line in file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6308497/perl-if-line-matches-regex-ignore-line-and-move-onto-next-line-in-file)

Comment: Why don't you try and process it line by line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you need:

```
my $data = "Smth\nfile:///myfile\nstring\nsmthelse\n";
$data =~ s/(file:\/\/\/.*?)\n(.*?)\n/\% $1\n\% $2\n/s;
print $data
```

Output:

```
Smth
% file:///myfile
% string
smthelse
```

So you can read a file into one string like:
`my $str = join '', <$fh>`
and do regexp with `s` key to process it as single line.
[Read](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)

---

**EDIT**:
If you do some stuff with every line and besides you want to change mentioned two lines as I did above, you can do so:

```
...
$data =~ s/(file:\/\/\/.*?)\n(.*?)\n/\% $1\n\% $2\n/s;
$file_str = $1;
$afterfile_str = $2;
my @data_arr = split /\n/, $data;
for(@data_arr) {
    # some code, perhaps using $file_str and $afterfile_str
    print $fh_out $_  . "\n";
}
```

Comment: Could you help me with how to integrate this?  My script so far does `open my $fh_in,` and `$fh_out` then does a bunch of complex stuff in a `while (<$fh_in>)` block, and then `print $fh_out $_;` I assume your code goes before the while, but it gave me a "Can't use global $1 in "my"" error.

Comment: Got it to work!  I simply put your code before the while block (without the smthings).  There was a trailing `;` missing after `$data`  and I just blindly copied it :) that was the error.  Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize, now it doesn't do my other transformations anymore, i.e., it seems to be ignoring everything within the `while` block.