# Regex Matching floating numbers in between commas

Tags: regex

I have a data set as follows

```
0,0 1868.37507375 -984.46051955 388.44592850 2 0    
    0,10 -7.0710700000e-01 -7.0710700000e-01 
        0.0000000000e+00 5.7735026919e-01 -5.7735026919e-01 5.77
0,11 7.0710700000e-01 7.0710700000e-01 0.0000000000e+00
    5.7735026919e-01 -5.7735026919e-01 5.35
```

I am trying to write a regex code inside a loop such that it matches **seven floating numbers between commas**. If the regex doesn't match, the loop will move to next set of digits. (except the very first digit before the first comma which is 0)

For example.
First set of digits will be matched until 5.77 b/c the data doesn't contain a comma after 5.77 and 5.77 is the seventh number after a comma.

The next set of digits is matched until 5.35 b/c the data lacks a comma after 5.35 and 5.35 is the seventh number after a comma

```
Line 1: 0,0 1868.37507375 -984.46051955 388.44592850 2 0    
        0,10 -7.0710700000e-01 -7.0710700000e-01 0.0000000000e+00
        5.7735026919e-01 -5.7735026919e-01 5.77

Line 2: 0,11 7.0710700000e-01 7.0710700000e-01 0.0000000000e+00
        5.7735026919e-01 -5.7735026919e-01 5.35
```

The closest answer I found was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6308497/perl-if-line-matches-regex-ignore-line-and-move-onto-next-line-in-file) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139715/regex-matching-numbers-with-floating-point). But it didn't end up being much help.

I am using Python 3.8.10

Answer (score 1):

This is not an easy task. I try to explain my regex as best I can.

```
(?<=,)\d+(\h+\-?\d+\.?\d*(e[+-]\d{2})?){6}
```

`(?<=,)` -> Have to start with comma.
`\d+` -> has digits on start. It means it matches whole numbers, not floating. If you want to change this to floating too, just delate stis part and `{6}` rewrite to `{7}`
`(\h+\-?\d+\.?\d*(e[+-]\d{2})?){6}` -> This matches floating point numbers 6 times, starting with horizontal white character.
`\h+` -> this is horizontal white character 1 or more.
`\-?` -> this is "-" 0 or 1 time.
`\d+` -> this is 1 or more numbers
`\.?` -> this is 1 or 0 "."
`\d*` -> this is 0 or more numbers
`(e[+-]\d{2})?)` -> this is e part

[image: Try this site]